# NSURLComponents changes %2B to + on adding a new query Item

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, url, nsurl

When I add a query Item then NSURLComponents changes %2B to + while %7B remains unchanged. From my understanding it should either decode both '+' and '{' why does it decode just one of them ?

```
  NSString *urlString = @"http://www.example.com?a=%7B1%2B2%7D";
  NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:urlString];
  NSLog(@"%@",components);
  // <NSURLComponents 0x7ffc42c19d40> {scheme = http, user = (null), password = (null), host = www.example.com, 
  // port = (null), path = , query = a=%7B1%2B2%7D, fragment = (null)}
  NSURLQueryItem *queryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"hl" value:@"en-us"];
  components.queryItems = [components.queryItems arrayByAddingObject:queryItem];
  NSLog(@"%@",components);
  // <NSURLComponents 0x7ffc42c19d40> {scheme = http, user = (null), password = (null), host = www.example.com, 
  // port = (null), path = , query = a=%7B1+2%7D&hl=en-us, fragment = (null)}
```

Comment: This is an actually existing problem, I don't know why downvotes this?

Answer (score 1):

The '+' character is legal in the query component so it does not need to be percent-encoded.

Some systems use the '+' as a space and require '+' the plus character to be percent-encoded. However, that kind of two stage encoding (converting plus sign to %2B and then converting space to plus sign) is prone to errors because it easily leads to encoding problems. It also breaks if the URL is normalized (syntax normalization of URLs includes the removal of all unnecessary percent-encoding -- see rfc3986 section 6.2.2.2).

So, if you need that behavior because of the server your code is talking to, you'll handle that extra transformation(s) yourself. Here's a snippet of code that shows what you need to do both ways:

```
NSURLComponents components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
NSArray items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"name" value:@"Value +"], nil];
[components setQueryItems:items];
NSLog(@"URL queryItems: %@", [components queryItems]);
NSLog(@"URL string before: %@", [components string]);
// Replace all "+" in the percentEncodedQuery with "%2B" (a percent-encoded +) and then replace all "%20" (a percent-encoded space) with "+" 
components.percentEncodedQuery = [[components.percentEncodedQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"URL string after: %@", [components string]);
// This is the reverse if you receive a URL with a query in that form and want to parse it with queryItems 
components.percentEncodedQuery = [[components.percentEncodedQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%20"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2B" withString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"URL string back: %@", [components string]);
NSLog(@"URL queryItems: %@", [components queryItems]);
```

The output is:

```
URL queryItems: ( " {name = name, value = Value +}" ) 
URL string before: ?name=Value%20+ 
URL string after: ?name=Value+%2B 
URL string back: ?name=Value%20+ 
URL queryItems: ( " {name = name, value = Value +}" )
```